# Referencing a row with blank cells inbetween and returning results from another row without blank cells inbetween

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a row that with cells spaced out evenly between eachother. I would like every 8th cell in that row to reference a cell in another sheet where there are no spaces between cells. I have a lot of data in this row so I don't want to do anything that will slow down the already large document and no VB code.

Comment: To clarify, do you have a sheet with values in consecutive columns, like A, B, C,...; and on another sheet, you want the cell in column A to reference column A on the first sheet, Column I to reference the cell in column B, column Q to reference the cell in column C, etc.?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Since this is not a script/formula writing service, it would be very helpful to know what you have already tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: The cells in the sheet I want to reference to are consecutive. The column that I want to display the results has cells spaced out with 7 blank cells in between each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the gist of how to accomplish that.

Say the source values on sheet1 are on row 3, starting in column C; so C3, D3, E3, etc.  The display cells are on sheet 2 in row 5, starting in column B, then every 8th cell, so B5, J5, R5, etc.  I purposely used different rows and starting columns for illustration.  It might be simpler in your case.

So you want B5 to display C3, J5 to display D3, R5 to display E3, etc.  There are two common ways to do that, using either OFFSET or INDIRECT.  I'll illustrate both.

**Column Calculation:** For either, you need to calculate the number of column increments (an increment is 8 on sheet2 vs. 1 on sheet1).  The formula for just that would be:

```
(COLUMN()-COLUMN(B5))/8  or in this example:
(COLUMN()-2)/8
```

The empty COLUMN() function returns the column of the cell it is in.  For each display cell on sheet2, its column, minus the first column in the series, divided by 8, gives you the number of column increments on sheet1.

For **OFFSET**, you would use it like this.  The formula in the sheet2 cells would be:

```
=OFFSET(sheet1!C3,0,(COLUMN()-2)/8,1,1)
```

OFFSET works from an anchor cell (C3 in this example), then offsets 0 rows, offsets the number of columns calculated by the formula above, and returns a result 1 row by 1 column in size (a single single cell).

**INDIRECT** translates something you build, from text and calculations, into an address.  For this function, you need to add in the anchor point to locate the actual cell address.  INDIRECT allows you to use an alternate style of address specification that is handy for calculating columns; it refers to columns as numbers rather than letters.  Cell C3 would be R3C3, or row 3, column 3.

Adding in the column of the anchor would make the column calculation look like this:

```
(COLUMN()-COLUMN(B5))/8+COLUMN(sheet1!C3)  or in this example:
(COLUMN()-2)/8+3
```

Building the cell reference is done by concatenating text and calculated numbers:

```
=INDIRECT("sheet1!R3C"&(COLUMN()-2)/8+3,false)
```

The "false" indicates that the cell reference is in the "R1C1" style.

Set up either formula in the first display cell on sheet2, adjusting it for your spreadsheet layout.  Then copy it into each of the other display cells.